# android - How to set corner radius programmatically?

Tags: android, listview, textview, rounded-corners

I have two `ListViews` (leftList, rightList). I also have one `TextView` which I use as row view in both of them. 
I have a rectangle drawable shape and set it as background to the `TextView`.

I would like to change this shape and have rounded corners on the left.

What I tried :

```
       GradientDrawable gradientDrawable = new GradientDrawable();
       // gradientDrawable.setCornerRadius(30);
        ((GradientDrawable)gradientDrawable.mutate()).setCornerRadius(30);

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
            viewHolderPattern.digits.setBackground(gradientDrawable);
        }
```

I have created a new layout in drawable with the right corner radius set and set that to the textView with `setBackgroundRescource` but still didn't work.

**The TextView that I use as items in both listViews**

```
<TextView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/digitsTextView"
    android:textSize="15dp"
    android:paddingTop="7dp"
    android:paddingBottom="8dp"
    android:fontFamily="monospace"
    android:textColor="@color/selected_items"
    android:background="@drawable/digital_text_shape">
</TextView>
```

**Shape layout digital_text_shape.xml**

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <stroke
        android:width="1dp"
        android:color="@color/orange" />
    <solid android:color="@color/orange" />
    <corners
        android:bottomLeftRadius="20dp"
        android:bottomRightRadius="0dp"
        android:topLeftRadius="20dp"
        android:topRightRadius="0dp"
        />
    <padding
        android:bottom="0dp"
        android:left="20dp"
        android:right="0dp"
        android:top="0dp" />
</shape>
```

**Left list and Right list**

```
<!-- Left ListView -->
                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    >
                        <ListView
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent"
                            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                            android:id="@+id/left_listView"
                            android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
                            android:dividerHeight="0.1sp"
                            android:choiceMode="singleChoice"

                            >
                        </ListView>
                </LinearLayout>

                <!-- Right ListView -->
                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    >
                        <ListView
                            android:id="@+id/right_listView"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent"
                            android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
                            android:dividerHeight="0.1sp"
                            android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
                            >
                        </ListView>
                </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: You know, for TextViews you can just clsoe them with />. You don't need a second tag at the end unless there is something inside of it.

Comment: why not just have different viewholders that use different xml? And a recycler view.. seems like a lot of effort to use a list view for a complex list like this- recyclers are aimed at these rich, complex lists

Comment: What if you create two different TextView background xml files. One for left and one for right. And then if you are in your left view: textView.setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.leftTextViewBackground));, and in your right list view: textView.setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.rightTextViewBackground)); ?

Comment: @LunarWatcher you are right! Thank you for mentioning that!

Comment: @SaikCaskey I already have a viewholder, and in that I have the textView that I want to modify and I heard of recycler view and I will try that as well, but for now, I want to do this with lists.

Comment: @DadoZolic That's what I was thinking of as well, but I have not found that solution to be practical because I would have to create another layout but I will try this. Thank you!

Comment: i got lost, what actually do you want to achieve?

Comment: @pskink I have a `Text View` that I use as a row view in both my `List Views`  and I have created a drawable shape and set that as it's background. Now, I want to change the right corner radius of that shape but only in one of the `List views`. And I don't know how to do that programmatically.

Comment: see Rohit Suthar's answer below (instead of `setBackgroundDrawable` use `setBackground`)

Comment: I'm saying you should use a viewholder for left, and one for right - you'll find this makes much better sense when you try it, listviews are a more out-of-the-box thing, if you use the viewholder pattern (with defined view states and viewholders) you can squeeze more out of them, but I appreciate you experimenting with what you have, that's a good attitude

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Here example for how to create `GradientDrawable` shape programmatically.

```
GradientDrawable shape = new GradientDrawable();
shape.setShape(GradientDrawable.RECTANGLE);
shape.setColor(Color.RED);
shape.setStroke(3, Color.YELLOW);
```

For change the radius for all corners of the gradient.

```
shape.setCornerRadius(15);
```

For Change the radius for specific corners of the gradient.

```
shape.setCornerRadii(new float[] { 8, 8, 8, 8, 0, 0, 0, 0 });
```

---

You can use this drawable as a background as below :

```
view.setBackgroundDrawable(shape);
```

Comment: {mTopLeftRadius, mTopLeftRadius, mTopRightRadius, mTopRightRadius, mBottomRightRadius, mBottomRightRadius, mBottomLeftRadius, mBottomLeftRadius}

Comment: Call .mutate() on the drawable if it is used elsewhere to prevent those instances from changing as well

Answer (score 5):

The answer of @Rohit Suthar in Kotlin, with dp converted to pixel, and color resources:

```
private val STROKE_WIDTH_PX = 2.dpToPx
private val CORNER_RADIUS_PX = 5.dpToPx.toFloat()


val shape = GradientDrawable()
shape.shape = GradientDrawable.RECTANGLE
shape.setColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.pink))
shape.setStroke(STROKE_WIDTH_PX, ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.black))
// choose either cornerRadius or cornerRadii
shape.cornerRadius = CORNER_RADIUS_PX
shape.cornerRadii = floatArrayOf(
    // top left
    0f,
    0f,
    // top right
    CORNER_RADIUS_PX,
    CORNER_RADIUS_PX,
    // bottom right
    CORNER_RADIUS_PX,
    CORNER_RADIUS_PX,
    // bottom left
    0f,
    0f
)
view.background = shape
```

To convert dp to px:

```
val Int.dpToPx: Int
    get() = (this * Resources.getSystem().displayMetrics.density).toInt()
```